Curl no responsed to telegram bot api
i have trobles with getting data from telegram api, but wery interesting.
I use two computers. one as a server. Both PCs have the same API address.
The second computer works as a server on which I have two telegram bots running.
Today I encountered a problem that when sending a curl get request to a telegram, one bot returns nothing.
The second bot works correctly and receives updates as expected.
Both bots use the same library (functionality for sending a request.
When I launch bots on the first PC, the bots also work correctly.
i use long pool.
What I tried to do:

curl_getinfo = all fields (except request) are 0;
increased the request timeout by 90 seconds. If you remove timeouts, it doesn’t help.
running scripts on another computer works. Therefore, you can exclude the router/provider.
smoked the manual

